# string program for ice cream shop (Edited again)

Tags: c++, string, atoi

With the assistance of others, I have redone the code from scratch due to them pointing out numerous errors and things that wouldn't work. Thus I have changed the code massively.

I have the program working other than two formatting settings that I can't figure out how to get to work.

I need to only print "DAILY SCOOP REPORT" once at the top of the output, but I've moved it around but due to the way the arrays are set up I don't know where to put it.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
```

## include

## include

## include

## include

## include

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string flavor_input, Capitalize;
    string flavors[] = { "Chocolate", "Vanilla", "Strawberry", "Mint", "Rocky Road", "Mocha" }; 
    int scoop_count [6] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, scoops = 0, j, k;

```
bool valid_option; 

cout << "Welcome to Frozen Tongue Ice Cream Shop\n"<<endl;
cout << "Flavors avaliable: "<<endl;
cout << "Chocolate "<<endl;
cout << "Valnilla "<<endl;
cout << "Strawberry "<<endl;
cout << "Mint "<<endl;
cout << "Rocky Road "<<endl;
cout << "Mocha \n"<<endl;

while(true) { 

    cout << "Please enter the flavor of icecream sold or 'STOP' to exit.\n"<<endl;
    getline (cin, flavor_input); // getline causes rocky road to be accepted with a space between the words. 


    string::iterator it( flavor_input.begin());  //converting the first letter of input to uppercase if not already.

    if (it != flavor_input.end())
        flavor_input[0] = toupper((unsigned char)flavor_input[0]);

    while(++it != flavor_input.end())
    {
        *it = tolower((unsigned char)*it);
    }


    if (flavor_input == "STOP" || flavor_input == "Stop")
        break; 

    valid_option = false; 

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)  //Checks to see if input matches those of possible inputs.
        if(!flavor_input.compare(flavors[i]))
        {
            valid_option = true;
            break;
        }

        if(!valid_option)
        {
            cout << "Invalid Flavor. Try again.\n\n"; 
            flavor_input.clear();
            continue; 
        }

        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            if(!flavor_input.compare(flavors[i])) 
            {
                cout << "Enter how many scoops were sold: ";
                cin >> scoops;
                cin.ignore();
                scoop_count[i] += scoops; 
                scoops = 0; 
                cout << '\n';
                break;
            }
        }
}


for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    if(!scoop_count[i])
        continue;
    else
    {
        cout << "\nDAILY SCOOP REPORT: "<<endl;   
        cout << setiosflags( ios::left )
            << setw( 11 )  << flavors[i]
        << resetiosflags( ios::left )
            << setw( 4 ) << scoop_count[i] << endl;

    }
}


cin.get();
return 0;
```

}

Thanks again for all of the assistance. It is greatly appreciated.

---

---

Thanks to all the assistance and pointing me in the direction of what to study, I have the program completed other than one last part.

I figured out that why it wasn't working when I moved the "DAILY SCOOP REPORT" line around. I had renamed the file and when I compiled it, it was outputing the "last working configuration" kinda deal if that makes sense. So I created a new project (the .cpp file has to have a certain name for submission) and put the code in it. Now the line is printed only once.

In the code block below, I have it where it lowers casing for all other letters other than the first or so it seems to be doing. The reason I have the case coding the way I do is that the instructions want the flavor report to print out with first letter of each word cap and lower after that. I am going to look into how to cap the 2nd "R" in Rocky Road, but other than the ignore white-space I don't really know how. Do I need to parse the line?

Anyone to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

I tried but it gives error that in the first if statement "syntax error : identifier 'flavor_input'".

```
//converting the first letter of input to uppercase if not already.
```

string::iterator it( flavor_input.begin());

```
    if flavor_input = "rocky road"
        (it != flavor_input.end())
        flavor_input[6] = toupper((unsigned char)flavor_input[6]);

    if (it != flavor_input.end())
        flavor_input[0] = toupper((unsigned char)flavor_input[0]);

    while(++it != flavor_input.end())
    {
        *it = tolower((unsigned char)*it);
    }
```

Comment: You say that you can't get the program to compile.  Please post your compiler errors.  Additionally, is this homework?

Comment: This should be tagged as a Homework assignment.

Comment: +1 for making an attempt before posting.

Comment: I think it's obviously homework :) Also, in this case it seems fine as he is doing it himself, but needs help with a problem he's having

Comment: 1) You should name your user input var to something that makes a little more sense contextually, like 'numScoops' or something. Naming it the same as your function is a little confusing. 2) My C/C++ isn't that strong, but I don't think you can return a list of values like that in your count() function.

Comment: _


I have used edit to post changed code.

Does anyone know why I keep getting an error from browser saying that some script has stopped? Is it the live preview?

Comment: I have edited the code again. Tis a work in progress. lol. Any ideas about the script stopping that I mentioned in comment above this?

Answer (score 5):

`switch` doesn't work with strings.

You need to use the operator `==` to select the right choice like so:

```
string count = // ... something
if (count == "choc") {

}
else if (count == "van") {

}
else if (count == "str") {

} // .. etc
```

A few other things: make sure you spell `string` with a consistent case, all lower case and no upper case. `String` is something different than `string`.

Make sure you surround strings with double quotes `""` and not single quotes `''`. single quotes are for single characters like `'a'` or `'b'`. double quotes are for multiple characters strings like `"abc"` and `"hello"`

Having the word `count` as both the function name and an argument name is probably a bad idea and will not compile because the same name means two different things.

You can't return multiple values from a function. writing something like `return a,b,c;` doesn't mean what you probably want it to mean. the comma (`,`) operator allows several expressions to be evaluated in the same statement and the result is the value of the last expression so writing `return 1,2,3;` is exactly the same as writing `return 3;`

Answer (score 1):

C++ cannot switch on a string. Replace your `switch(count) {...}` with `if/else if` statements. Additionally the proper format for a string is "string", not 'string' (single quotes designate a single character, like: 'a'). Also, ensure that you always use the correct casing for string objects (`string` as opposed to `String`, like you have as your return values)

Other than that, it would be helpful to see the compiler errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at the whole thing, but this isn't going to do what you want:

```
if (flavor = 'STOP' || 'stop')
```

I think you need:

```
if (flavor.compare("STOP") == 0 || flavor.compare("stop") == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing I noticed in your source: you will have to omit the semicolons (-cola?) at the end of the following lines:

```
cout << "Please enter the flavor of icecream sold or 'STOP' to exit.\n"<<endl
     << "Flavors avaliable:\n"<<endl
     << "chocolate\n"<<endl
     << "valnilla\n"<<endl
     << "strawberry\n"<<endl
     << "mint\n"<<endl
     << "rocky road\n"<<endl
     << "mocha\n"<<endl
     << "Enter flavor : ";
```

This is just a single huge expression. The same applies to

```
cout << "\nDAILY SCOOP REPORT: \n"<<endl
     << "chocolate :"<<chocolate<<"\n"<<endl
     << "vanilla :"<<vanilla<<"\n"<<endl
     << "strawberry :"<<strawberry<<"\n"<<endl
     << "mint :"<<mint<<"\n"<<endl
     << "rocky road :"<<rocky_road<<"\n"<<endl
     << "mocha :"<<mocha<<"\n"<<endl;
```

Also: the `endl` and the `"\n"` are redundant. You will see the choices being separated by empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go down the problems I see.

```
String count (string& flavor, string& count, string& chocolate, string& vanilla, string& strawberry, string& mint, string& rocky_road, string& mocha);
```

You're using `String` here, I'm sure you meant `std::string` or just `string`.

Inside the count function (SO is truncating the code when pasted), you're ending the line with a semicolon after endl yet trying to continue the stream output. I think you meant

Next:

```
if (flavor = 'STOP' || 'stop')
```

I think you meant to use the `operator==` instead of `operator=`, which is assignment not comparison. Also, there are no junctions in c++, so you will have to write that out as:

```
if (flavor == 'STOP' || flavor == 'stop')
```

Next:

```
switch (count) { case 'choc' :
```

Two problems here. First, you can only use plain-old-data (pod) in switch statements. Using std::string in a switch will not automatically call operator==; you will have to use if/else statements. Also, string literals are double quoted whereas character literals are single quoted.

Next:

```
chocCount + count;
```

This isn't really a statement. I'm sure you meant `chocCount += count;`

Next:

```
if (flavor = chocolate) chocCount + count;
```

Again, you want to use `==` and `chocCount += count;`.

Most of these problems are repeated. You should fix each of these problems everywhere they exist. There may be other problems, but I was basically compiling that in my head.

I didn't read through all of it to find semantic problems, but your count function is clearly not returning a count (at least what I currently see posted). You are returning a String, which I assume you meant string.

That's all this human compiler is going to solve for 1 homework assignment. I could recommend you go read a [good C++ tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/).